# JQuery anonymous function not firing

Tags: jquery

JQuery newbie.

With this code the alert for '2' works, but never the alert '1'.
I can switch around the order and get the same result, and JQuery must be loaded otherwise neither would work.  So whats the problem with the declaration of the anonymous function?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('1');
        });

        $(document).ready(
            alert('2')
        );
     </script>
```

Comment: You're missing the function literals at `alert(2)`, did you know? Either method works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/W44s7/

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zgvjJ/.

Comment: @Rob W you need to use `no wrap (head)`. This will allow the anonymous function to fire first. They should not fire 1 -> 2, but 2 -> 1 based on his scenario.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy No it won't (in both cases 2 comes before 1). When using `no wrap`, the document is not ready yet at run-time. I deliberately used `no wrap` to show that `alert(2)` is immediately invoked, while `alert(1)` is properly queued. When `onload` or `domready` is used, the function passed to `$().ready` is immediately called, causing the order to be 1, 2.

Comment: @Rob W while the code you provided still works, because of other things, you're using `no wrap (body)` you are not inserting any script into the body, therefore it will fire at runtime regardless of the spec you provide. on jsFiddle, if you put <script> tags in the <html> section, you would use `no wrap (body)`, if you put the javascript in the javascript container, you would use `no wrap (head)`...[documentation supporting my claims...](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#choose-framework)

Answer (score 4):

You're not passing a function in the second call to `ready()`, but the value returned by `alert()` (i.e. `undefined`).

It means that `alert()` is called right away (without waiting for the document to become ready), then `undefined` is passed to `ready()`, which results in a no-op (or possibly an error, depending on the version of jQuery you're using).

Your first call is the right way to do it.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It correctly explains what is happening and why it is happening, and gives a suggested way to fix it (by using the first one which is correct).

Comment: Thanks for all the replies.
I understand that method '1' is correct.  But on my webpage the alert'1' is never shown and '2' does get shown.  I see however on jsfiddle that it works on there.
So I suppose my question is 'what would be stopping the code working when an anonymous function() is used?'

Comment: @simon, are you using a recent release of jQuery? Passing `undefined` to `ready()` in older versions *possibly might* break things and prevent previously registered handlers from firing.

Comment: I am using jquery-1.7.2.js, jquery-ui-1.8.20.js and jqgrid within asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 2):

It's either

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 ...
});
```

or

```
$(function() {
 ...
});
```

These are equivalent. Calling without `function(){}` as in your second example is wrong.

Having several document ready functions makes no sense. Just put the code together into one function.